# How do I create bottom braces decorations with Tikz-Feynman?

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I'm trying to create a brace on the bottom in Ti*k*z Feynman, but no matter what I try, the brace remains on the bottom. This is what I have:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Sorry if the annotation was a bit bold; I forgot to change the brush width. Anyway, how do I turn this brace upside down? This is my current code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (i3) {\(u\)};
            \vertex [above right=of i3] (i4);
            \vertex [above left=of i4] (i5) {\(u\)};
            \vertex [right=0.5cm of i3] (i6) {\(d\)};
            \vertex [above right=of i6] (i7);
            \vertex [above left=of i7] (i8) {\(d\)};
            \vertex [right=0.5cm of i6] (a) {\(d\)};
            \vertex [above right=of a] (b);
            \vertex [above left=of b] (c) {\(u\)};
            \vertex [above right=of b] (d);
            \vertex [above right=of d] (e) {\(\overline{\nu}_e\)};
            \vertex [right=of d] (f);
            \vertex [above=0.2cm of f] (g) {\(e^-\)};
            \diagram* {
                (i3) -- [fermion] (i4) -- [fermion] (i5),
                (i6) -- [fermion] (i7) -- [fermion] (i8),
                (a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (c),
                (b) -- [boson, edge label=$W^-$] (d) -- [anti fermion] (e),
                (d) -- [fermion] (g)
            };
            \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (i5.north west) -- (c.north east) node [pos=0.5, above] {\large \(p^+\)};
            \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (i3.south west) -- (a.south east) node [pos=0.5, above] {\large \(n^0\)};
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: From the duplicate: `decoration={brace,mirror}`.

Comment: @Marijn This works for me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the most elegant solution. I replaced `(i3.south west) -- (a.south east)` with `(i3.south west) -- (a.south east)` and `node [pos=0.5, above]` with `[pos=0.5, below]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (i3) {\(u\)};
            \vertex [above right=of i3] (i4);
            \vertex [above left=of i4] (i5) {\(u\)};
            \vertex [right=0.5cm of i3] (i6) {\(d\)};
            \vertex [above right=of i6] (i7);
            \vertex [above left=of i7] (i8) {\(d\)};
            \vertex [right=0.5cm of i6] (a) {\(d\)};
            \vertex [above right=of a] (b);
            \vertex [above left=of b] (c) {\(u\)};
            \vertex [above right=of b] (d);
            \vertex [above right=of d] (e) {\(\overline{\nu}_e\)};
            \vertex [right=of d] (f);
            \vertex [above=0.2cm of f] (g) {\(e^-\)};
            \diagram* {
                (i3) -- [fermion] (i4) -- [fermion] (i5),
                (i6) -- [fermion] (i7) -- [fermion] (i8),
                (a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (c),
                (b) -- [boson, edge label=$W^-$] (d) -- [anti fermion] (e),
                (d) -- [fermion] (g)
            };
            \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (i5.north west) -- (c.north east) node [pos=0.5, above] {\large \(p^+\)};
            \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (a.south east) -- (i3.south west) node [pos=0.5, below] {\large \(n^0\)};
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I think @Marjin 's comment on the main question is a simpler way to do this. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: @AkhileshBalaji: `brace, mirror` only changes the direction of the brace and is cetainly a more elegant solution than switching the start and end coordinate as I did in my answer. As far as I can tell, `mirror`, however, does not alter the position of the text. You still need `below` instead of `above`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes, that's right, I did that. Thanks for the idea!